# Chrome: custom scrollbar problem when both scroll bars are applied

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

Check the following snippet in Chrome/Safari/new Edge, and scroll the container to the very bottom:

```css
body { background-color: #fff }

section {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: overlay;
}

.force-overflow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, yellow, orange);
  height: 600px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #999;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #444;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
</section>
```

This works as expected.

Now if we add a **horizontal** overflow as well:

```css
body { background-color: #fff }

section {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: overlay;
}

.force-overflow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, yellow, orange);
  height: 600px;
  width: 1200px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #999;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #444;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
</section>
```

and scroll to the very right/bottom, we get this:

[image] [image]

I know I can fix this using `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: overlay;`, but I really would like to stick with `overlay` because it prevents your layout from "jumping" as soon as a scrollbar shows up/vanishes.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a hacky solution is to add some box-shadow to cover this part:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0;
}
```

```css
body { background-color: #fff }

section {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: overlay;
}

.force-overflow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, yellow, orange);
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #999;
  color:#999;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #444;
  color:#444;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: So does this look like a Chrome bug to you?

Comment: @connexo not really because when using overlay you cannot scroll past the width/height of the scrollbar that is now part of the content so you have that offset. I guess the Developpers decided to do an easy implementation by keeping the original scrollbar (you can notice no dimension change between auto and overlay) and due to this you have this restriction. Probably if you raise this as bug, they can improve the implementation

Comment: @connexo there is no issue with one scroll because if the other one is no present you can scroll **all** the area. The issue is that when both are there, each one will have the dimension restriction of the other and cannot scroll past its dimension. Yes my hack need to be adjusted based on each case, actually I don't know the exact formula but it's related to the dimension of the scroll, the container and the overflowing content (will update later if I find a generic way to get a precise value)

Comment: Well, unfortunately, as it stands, this cannot be applied as a general fix. I really don't want to involve any Javascript here; I might resort to doing `overflow-y: auto;` while sticking to `overflow-x: overlay;`.

Comment: @connexo simply make sure it's big enough to always cover the gap, for sure it won't be bigger than 10px (the dimension of the scroll) and it's for sure smaller .. maybe around 7px/8px will cover all the cases